# Order preserving,reflecting map between lattices is join-homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $L_1, L_2$ be lattices and $f: L_1\to L_2$ a bijective (suffices to demand surjectivity) mapping such that
$$\forall a,b\in L_1,\quad a\leq b\iff f(a)\leq f(b) $$

> Show that $f$ is an isomorphism of lattices.

It remains to verify whether $f$ is a homomorphism and for that it suffices to check whether $f$ is a $\vee$-homomorphism ($\wedge$-hom is established dually) that is
$$\forall a,b\in L_1,\quad f(a\vee b) \overset{?}= f(a)\vee f(b) $$
Since $a \leq a\vee b$ and $b\leq a\vee b$, then 
$$f(a)\leq f(a\vee b)\quad\mbox{and}\quad f(b)\leq f(a\vee b) $$
By definition of least upper bound we have
$$f(a)\vee f(b)\leq f(a\vee b) $$
But how does one establish the converse inequality i.e
$$f(a\vee b)\overset{?}\leq f(a)\vee f(b) $$
Lecture notes say this is obvious :(

We could assume $f(a\vee b) > f(a)\vee f(b)\geq f(a)$, for instance. Then order reflection gives $a\vee b\geq a$, but so what? Or is it $a\vee b > a$, then $a\vee b > b$, but still, so what? I don't understand how this claim is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is $c$ such that $f(c)=f(a)\vee f(b)$. Since $f(c)=f(a)\vee f(b)\leq f(a\vee b)$, we have that $c\leq a\vee b$. If $c<a\vee b$, then either $a\not\leq c$ or $b\not\leq c$ since $a\vee b$ was the least upper bound. Without loss of generality, assume $a\not\leq c$. Then $f(a)\not\leq f(c)=f(a)\vee f(b)$; a contradiction. Thus $c\not< a\vee b$.

Comment: Was it obvious to you? :) Goes to show, one must use all the assumptions they have. I disregarded surjectivity as something insignificant :(

Comment: I wouldn't say 'obvious', but maybe 'clear' :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to argue by contradiction.

There is a $c$ such that $f(c)=f(a)\vee f(b)$. In particular $f(a)\leq f(c)$ and $f(b)\leq f(c)$. Since $f$ preserves order this implies $a\leq c$ and $b\leq c$, i.e. $a\vee b \leq c$. Using the order preserving property of $f$ again we get $f(a\vee b) \leq f(c)=f(a)\vee f(b)$, as desired.

Comment: I have digivolved since I posted that question, but thanks for your input :)